Два одинаковых обработчика кнопок, но одна кнопка не работет
У меня есть обработчики кнопок, выполняют они одинаковую функцю, но первая кнопка работает, а вторая нет
В ошибке выдает, что чат не найден
def callback_inline(call):
    user_id = call.data.split("_")[1]
    if call.data.startswith("add"):
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Введите сумму для пополнения баланса:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_amount, user_id)
    elif call.data.startswith("not_add"):
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Введите сумму для пополнения баланса:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_amountt, user_id)


def process_amount(message, user_id):
    amount = float(message.text)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ggovno.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = balance + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (amount, user_id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    bot.send_message(user_id, f"Ваш баланс пополнен на {amount}.")

def process_amountt(message, user_id):
    amount = float(message.text)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ggovno.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = balance + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (amount, user_id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    bot.send_message(user_id, f"Ваш баланс пополнен на {amount}.")```

